# bash shell automatically creating user - adduser

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I need to automatically create a user by reading lines of a file that contains username, home directory and full name.

I am new to bash shell scripting and it is very confusing to me.

There is something wrong with my adduser command. It gives the error - adduser: Only one or two names allowed.

following is the full script -

```
while read line;
do 
      fieldnumbers=$(echo $line | grep - o " " | wc - l)
      username=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f 1)
      home=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f 2)
      firstname=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f 3)

      if [[ "$fieldnumbers" -eq b4 ]]
      then
               middlename=""
      else
               middlename=$(echo $line | rev | cut -d' ' -f 2)

      lastname=$(echo $line | rev | cut -d' ' -f 1)
      password=$(echo pwgen 7 1) #create random password
      fullname="$firstname $middlename $lastname"

      echo "username is : $username"
      sudo adduser --gecos $fullname --disabled-password --home $home $username

      echo 'username:$password' | chpasswd
       echo "Password is for $username is: $password"
done < users.txt
```

I am sure that this script is riddled with syntax errors. Please help. my brain is fried.

Comment: Use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check your syntax

Comment: You are missing a `fi` to start with.  There are better ways of splitting those fields than by using external programs like `grep` and `cut`.  What's `b4` all about?

Comment: its supposed to be 4. thats a mistake. ty for the fi correction.

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always quote your variables unless you deliberately want to split the value into separate words.

```
sudo adduser --gecos "$fullname" --disabled-password --home "$home" "$username"
```

Also, you have to use double quotes around strings containing variables, not single quotes, if you want the variables to be expanded.

[Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

So this line:

```
echo 'username:$password' | chpasswd
```

should be:

```
echo "username:$password" | chpasswd
```

Comment: one more problem. What is wrong with the echo commands that show the generated password?

Comment: You mean the last echo command? It looks fine to me. What does shellcheck.net say about it?

Comment: BTW, is there a reason you're doing all that echoing and cutting instead of just `while read username home fullname`?